# React Native Android: importing another project using gradle is not working

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I am building an Android project using ReactNative. I am trying to import another Android project through Gradle into my React Native Android project. But it is throwing an error when I run the project.

I copied another project folder into my ReactNative project, {root}/anotherproject

Then I changed the settings.gradle file into this

```
rootProject.name = 'TestReactNative'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':anotherproject'
project(':anotherproject').projectDir = new File('../anotherproject')
```

When I run "react-native run-android", I am getting the following error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Project 'app' not found in root project 'TestReactNative'.
```

What is wrong with what I did and how can I fix it?

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 1):

In the settings.gradle, you should add the path to the android/app of anotherproject.

```
include ':anotherproject'
project(':anotherproject').projectDir = file('../anotherproject/android/app')
```

And in your parent project's android/app/build.gradle, you need to add anotherproject as a dependency.

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(":anotherproject")
}
```

Lastly, anotherproject should only have the app folder in the android directory. And in app/build.gradle, make sure it is a library not an application like so:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.library"
```